# ssh passwordless still asking for password

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to setup an SSH passwordless login but can't seem to get it to work...here is what I did:

Host: (OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips)

1.) ssh-keygen -t dsa

2.) copied the id_dsa.pub to the remote server `OpenSSH_6.2p2 (CentrifyDC build 5.1.3-204) (CentrifyDC build 5.1.3-204), OpenSSL 0.9.8zc-fips`

3.) ran `cat id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys` and `cat id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys2` on the remote server

Remote:

1.) `chmod 700` on the .ssh dir

2.) `chmod 700` on both authorized_keys and authorized_key2

what am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't you try looking at the error messages? The way to do it is to start ssh by hand on the server, `service ssh stop && /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd` (if you are using Debian), then trying to connect and seeing what happens. Otherwise, look into `/var/log/auth.log` or whatever your distro has. You can also do it with `cd /var/log && grep -nrI ssh`.

Comment: well, i've always just done ssh-keygen and generated the rsa file.. But A)I notice your path for authorized_keys is wrong, and id_rsa.pub is meant to be on the local computer while the authorized_keys file you're appending to is on the remote server. Also this isn't a problem but it's senseless to have a 7 permission on something that is a data file file. Can do chmod 600 id_rsa (local).  chmod 644 id_rsa.pub (local and remote)  chmod 600 authorized_keys Some ideas re chmod permissions here http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html

Comment: also check sshd_config has something along the lines of PubkeyAuthentication yes.  And your path to authorized_keys on the remote host.. should be like `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`   You can use `ssh-copy-id`  see http://superuser.com/questions/959671/how-are-public-keys-sent-to-servers-and-how-are-private-keys-used-for-ssh